# Adding object to HttpSession fails in SpringBoot with Redis

Tags: java, redis, spring-boot, httpsession

When I try to add an object into the session as follows:

```
HttpSession session = ....
MyObject object = ....
session.setAttribute("my_object", object);
```

then I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.data.redis.serializer.SerializationException: 
Cannot serialize; nested exception is   
org.springframework.core.serializer.support.SerializationFailedException:
Failed to serialize object using DefaultSerializer; nested exception is 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DefaultSerializer requires a  
Serializable payload but received an object of type [MyObject]
```

What should I do to instruct REDIS in serializing the object `MyObject`?

Answer (score 4):

I guess that the exception is already telling you what is going wrong.
Simply try to make `MyObject` implementing `Serializable`